# How to reduce the space in this letter "、" with css?

Tags: css

How to reduce the space in this letter  `、` with css ?

```
パサつき、ひろがり、うねりフリーへ。
```

this is japanese language

Answer (score 2):

The character you are referring to, "`、`", is called an IDEOGRAPHIC COMMA and is Unicode character U+3001.

You can use the CSS property `letter-spacing` to reduce the spacing between letters.

In the example below, I've reduced the letter spacing of the character by 0.5em to show this:

```css
span {
  letter-spacing: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello &#x3001; World</p>
<p>Hello <span>&#x3001;</span> World</p>
```

The first line has no reduction.

The second line has a `span` containing the character with the 0.5em reduction in `letter-spacing`.

You may need to adjust the size of the spacing to get the correct effect.  I would recommend sticking with `em` units rather than `px` as they will scale proportionally with whichever font you are using.

In your example specifically:

```css
span {
  letter-spacing: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<p>パサつき、ひろがり、うねりフリーへ。</p>
<p>パサつき<span>、</span>ひろがり<span>、</span>うねりフリーへ。</p>
```